# How do I localize changes to a variable inside a Do-loop?

Tags: scoping

I want to change the increment value inside the do loop . But i dont know why it remains for the first declared value?

```
h = 0.1; x = 1.0;
Do[
 x = x + h;
 h++;
 Print[h];
 , {t, 0.0, 1.0, h}]

1.1

2.1

3.1

4.1

5.1

6.1

7.1

8.1

9.1

10.1

11.1
```

I actually want to change the value of increment (h) inside using do loop only.Can anyone help me to fix this

Comment: This is not possible. Either pre-generate the `t` values and use `Do[..., {t, tvals}]` or use `While`.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for the reply can you post your idea with " Do" loop . I have tried with "While" but the program is too slow when i run for many iterations .

Comment: Well, your example would quit after the first iteration if `h` could be changed. Can you show a realistic example?

Comment: @Szabolcs. It is perfectly possible and actually easy since an iteration variable isn't needed by the computation described.

Comment: @m_goldberg I think we read the questions differently. I thought that OP had a starting value for the iterator and an ending value, but the iterator was incremented in a special, non-uniform way. In your solution, you fixed the number of iterations in advance at 11. I interpreted the question as wanting to stop when `t` reaches `1.0` (or some other threshold). Determining how many iterations this takes is not trivial in general. However, given that `h` becomes larger than 1 already in the 2nd step, and that `t`'s upper bound is `1.0`, the example shown by the OP does not make any sense to me.

Comment: That is why I asked for a realistic example.

Answer (score 2):

This is the rare occasion where `For` can do something that `Do` cannot do right from the start: Messing around with its iterator.

This is the way to do it with `For`:

```
tmax = 100000.;
hinc = 1.;
{x0, t0, h0} = {1.0, 0., 0.1};

Module[{x, t, h},
  For[x = x0; t = t0; h = h0;, t <= tmax,
   t += h;
   x += h;
   h += hinc
   ];
  x
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.00173, 1.00055*10^6}

The variant with while could look like this:

```
Module[{x, t, h},
  x = x0; t = t0; h = h0;
  While[t <= tmax,
   x += h;
   t += h;
   h += hinc;
   ];
  x
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.001732, 1.00055*10^6}

I thought about suffesting `NestWhile` but that one is a bit slower

```
First@NestWhile[
   {#[[1]] + #[[3]], #[[2]] + #[[3]], #[[3]] + hinc} &,
   {x0, t0, h0},
   #[[2]] <= tmax &
   ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.004578, 1.00055*10^6}

In view of how complicated it is to set up, even if it has scoping built-in, I would not suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

You can localize `h` within the Do-loop with `Module` which will keep the global `h` unchanged. Like so.

```
h = 0.1;
x = 1.0;
Module[{h = h},
  Do[x += h++; Print[Row[{x, "   ", h}]], 11]]
```

[image: print]

```
h
```

> `0.1`

Note how much the `Do` expression can be simplified.